# c# recursive function help understanding how it works?

Tags: c#, recursion, yield-return

I need help to understand how a function is working;: it is a `recursive` function with yield return but I can't figure out how it works. It is used calculate a `cumulative` density function (approximate) over a set of data.
Thanks a lot to everyone.

```
/// Approximates the cumulative density through a recursive procedure 
/// estimating counts of regions at different resolutions.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="data">Source collection of integer values</param>
/// <param name="maximum">The largest integer in the resulting cdf (it has to be a power of 2...</param>
/// <returns>A list of counts, where entry i is the number of records less than i</returns>


public static IEnumerable<int> FUNCT(IEnumerable<int> data, int max)
  {
    if (max == 1)
        {
            yield return data.Count();
        }
        else
        {
            var t = data.Where(x => x < max / 2);
            var f = data.Where(x => x > max / 2);

            foreach (var value in FUNCT(t, max / 2))
                yield return value;  

            var count = t.Count();
            f = f.Select(x => x - max / 2);
            foreach (var value in FUNCT(f, max / 2))   
                yield return value + count;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Stepping through the code with the debugger can help you understand what's happening with the data.

Comment: Do you understand how both recursion and `yield return` work in general? That would be the first step to understanding the code.

Comment: I used the debug, but still not understand some part...maybe the problem is that I don' t understand well yield return...

Comment: You might have a bug in the line `var f = data.Where(x => x > max / 2);`  This should probably be `>=` rather than `>`.

Comment: Also I believe the comment should read `<returns>A list of counts, where entry i is the number of records less than 2 ^ i</returns>`

Comment: Every time you write "c sharp" instead of "c#", a musician strangles a kitten

Comment: @drf the >= is not so important, I can underestimate the cdf...with th equal I think I overestimate..

Comment: @aranda: the count are < i (approximate)

Comment: @aranda, the comment in the source is correct.  (e.g., given initial inputs [0,1,0,3,2,2] and initial max 4, output should be [2, 3, 5, 6] (i.e., number of entries less than 1, 2, 3, and 4).)

Comment: @dave, the >= is actually critically important for this algorithm.  Since it's a recursive algorithm where each iteration divides the set into 2, using > instead of >= causes half the values (those not divisible by 2) to be discarded.

Comment: @drf, mmm I don`t understand...I run the algorithm, it work well for what I need, as I said it understimates a little but it is fine for what I need. If I put the = the function overestimates the count and I don't want it.

Comment: Someone is able to make an example with some (little) number step by step? Becouse I tried but each time I get lost at some point in the middle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence, IEnumerable functions that use yield return function slightly differently from traditional recursive functions.  As a base case, suppose you have:

```
IEnumerable<int> F(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
    {
       yield return 1;
       yield return 2;
       // implied yield return break;
    }
    // Enter loop 1
    foreach (var v in F(n - 1))
        yield return v;
    // End loop 1
    int sum = 5;
    // Enter loop 2
    foreach (var v in F(n - 1))
        yield return v + sum;
    // End loop 2
    // implied yield return break;
}
void Main()
{
   foreach (var v in F(2))
       Console.Write(v);
   // implied return
}
```

`F` takes the basic orm of the original `FUNCT`.  If we call F(2), then walking through the yields:

```
F(2)
|   F(1)
|   |   yield return 1
|   yield return 1
Console.Write(1);
|   |  yield return 2    
|   yield return 2
Console.Write(2)
|   |  RETURNS
|   sum = 5;
|   F(1)
|   |  yield return 1
|   yield return 1 + 5
Console.Write(6)
|   |  yield return 2
|   yield return 2 + 5
Console.Write(7)
|   |  RETURNS
|   RETURNS
RETURNS
```

And `1267` is printed.  Note that the `yield return` statement yields control to the caller, but that the next iteration causes the function to continue where it had previously yielded.

The CDF method does adds some additional complexity, but not much.  The recursion splits the collection into two pieces, and computes the CDF of each piece, until max=1.  Then the function counts the number of elements and yields it, with each yield propogating recursively to the enclosing loop.

To walk through `FUNCT`, suppose you run with `data=[0,1,0,1,2,3,2,1]` and `max=4`. Then running through the method, using the same `Main` function above as a driver, yields:

```
FUNCT([0,1,0,1,2,3,2,1], 4)
| max/2 = 2
| t = [0,1,0,1,1]
| f = [3] // (note: per my comment to the original question,
|         // should be [2,3,2] to get true CDF.  The 2s are
|         // ignored since the method uses > max/2 rather than
|         // >= max/2.)
| FUNCT(t,max/2) = FUNCT([0,1,0,1,1], 2)
| |    max/2 = 1
| |    t = [0,0]
| |    f = [] // or [1,1,1]
| |    FUNCT(t, max/2) = FUNCT([0,0], 1)
| |    |   max = 1
| |    |   yield return data.count = [0,0].count = 2
| |    yield return 2
| yield return 2
Console.Write(2)
| |    |   RETURNS
| |    count = t.count = 2
| |    F(f, max/2) = FUNCT([], 1)
| |    |   max = 1
| |    |   yield return data.count = [].count = 0
| |    yield return 0 + count = 2
| yield return 2
Console.Write(2)
| |    |   RETURNS
| |    RETURNS
| count = t.Count() = 5
| f = f - max/2 = f - 2 = [1]
| FUNCT(f, max/2) = FUNCT([1], 2)
| |    max = 2
| |    max/2 = 1
| |    t = []
| |    f = [] // or [1]
| |    FUNCT(t, max/2) = funct([], 1)
| |    |   max = 1
| |    |   yield return data.count = [].count = 0
| |    yield return 0
| yield return 0 + count = 5
Console.Write(5)
| |    |   RETURNS
| |    count = t.count = [].count = 0
| |    f = f - max/2 = []
| |    F(f, max/2) = funct([], 1)
| |    |   max = 1
| |    |   yield return data.count = [].count = 0
| |    yield return 0 + count = 0 + 0 = 0
| yield return 0 + count = 0 + 5 = 5
Console.Write(5)
| |    RETURNS
| RETURNS
RETURNS
```

So this returns the values (2,2,5,5).  (using `>=` would yield the values (2,5,7,8) -- note that these are the exact values of a scaled CDF for non-negative integral data, rather than an approximation).

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. Assuming you understand how [yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) works, the comments on the function (in your question) are very helpful. I've commented the code as I understand it which might help:

```
    public static IEnumerable<int> FUNCT(IEnumerable<int> data, int max)
    {
        if (max == 1)
        {
            // Effectively the end of the recursion.
            yield return data.Count();
        }
        else
        {
            // Split the data into two sets
            var t = data.Where(x => x < max / 2);
            var f = data.Where(x => x > max / 2);

            // In the set of smaller numbers, recurse to split it again
            foreach (var value in FUNCT(t, max / 2))
                yield return value;

            // For the set of smaller numbers, get the count.
            var count = t.Count();

            // Shift the larger numbers so they are in the smaller half.
            // This allows the recursive function to reach an end.
            f = f.Select(x => x - max / 2);

            // Recurse but add the count of smaller numbers. We already know there 
            // are at least 'count' values which are less than max / 2.
            // Recurse to find out how many more there are.
            foreach (var value in FUNCT(f, max / 2))   
                yield return value + count;
        }
    }
```